# Regex alternative to find files

Tags: bash

When I attempt the `regex` alternative to find files in my downloads, especially, for this instance to get `.csv` extensions, I get nothing returned.

I know I can get these files with:

```
find . -name '*.csv'
```

However, none of my regex alternatives with find work, for example:

```
 find . -regextype sed -regex '.csv$'
```

Returns nothing even though it's a working regular expression. Neither does the following:

```
find . -regextype sed -regex '(?<=\/)(.*?).csv$'
```

When my files look like:

```
./audienceBuild1.py
./audiences.json
./authorize
./bingoXandr.csv
./Book1.xlsx
./Book10.xlsx
./book2.pdf
./Campaigns (1).csv
./Campaigns.csv
./catalogue.csv
./coords.jl
```

Comment: Okay, what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following

```bash
find . -regextype sed -regex '.*\.csv'
```

What does this mean?

- `.*` refers to the **longest string** containing **any element** in this pattern;
- `\.csv` refers to the literal string `.csv`

Note how the dot needs to be escaped, otherwise it is seen as **any character**.

I believe this should work.

Comment: The problem is these all work but nothing appears in my console :/ besides the first example I provided. `regex` outputs nothing

Comment: try the following it  did work for me on a directory with many csv files `'.*\.csv'`

Comment: That works! I wonder whether it's because I am using `cygwin`? Therefore, I have to take the full-path into account

Comment: it shouldn't need to, after all it is searching in the . directory, in fact I did try your suggestions and they also didn't print out results, I believe it may be due to the regex syntax used where `*` by itself does not refer to anything, for it is only a closure to refer to no elements or more elements, the `.` is essential in this syntax.

Comment: Weird! you may be right, although when I test with `regex101`, it captures successfully even when I attempt `(?<=)(.*?csv)$`

Comment: https://regex101.com is not valid for many traditional Unix tools; it supports a couple of regex dialects but not the POSIX ones. Perhaps see the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) for some background and several common beginner FAQs.

Comment: The beef is that the regex needs to match the entrire file name, unlike the regex you pass to e.g. `grep` or `sed`.

Comment: You should take some care with regex101 and make sure to select the correct engine, for example, unix does not recognize `()` as special characters instead `\(\)` should work

Comment: @tripleee that might be the issue, I keep grabbing with `group 1`, but the only working options grab with `group 0`. I cannot understand why mine captures only at `group 1` though, so I'll have to search that up.

Comment: @greybrunix that is helpful! I have attempted `'.*\.*\(csv\)$'` and it works when escaping the brackets but return nothing when not escaped. I'll have to find out why the original options does not work.

Comment: This works also `\(.*csv\)$` for whatever reason the lookahead fails :/

Comment: I believe lookaheads and lookbehinds are not in the POSIX flavor so it might not be recognized

Comment: I have tested all regextypes with find and none work with any simple lookbehind I have produced. It may be a linux thing, I wonder if anyone has any successful expressions with these implemented with find.

Comment: Indeed, as already explained above, lookaheads and lookbehinds are a relatively recent innovation which is not supported by most traditional regex tools. Again, the tag info page has some background and pointers to further information.